# "flow check-contents" and "flow suggest"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why does "flow check-contents" require use of < to redirect a file into it, but "flow suggest" does not?  It seems like check-contents should assume the command-line arguments are file paths to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

`flow check-contents < filename.js` checks the whole project, including `filename.js`. the most common use case is editor integration, where you want to check the project against an unsaved version of a file; in that case you'd do `flow check-contents filename.js < unsaved editor buffer`, which tells flow to temporarily replace the contents of `filename.js` and recheck the whole project.

if you're piping in a saved file, you can alternatively run `flow` (aka `flow status`) instead of piping it in, since that also checks the entire project.